# Custom entity resolver for XMLStreamReader not working

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml to parse with XMLStreamReader, but it has some html entities (not part of xml standard) like accented characters that make the `next()` method to throw `XMLStreamException: The entity "uacute" was referenced, but not declared.`

I try to add a custom entity resolver implementing `XMLResolver` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLResolver.html), which documentation states that:

> If an application wishes to perform custom entity resolution it must register an instance of this interface with the XMLInputFactory using the setXMLResolver method.

Ok, so I made this class to reproduce the error:

```
private void testXMLResolver() throws XMLStreamException {
    String xml = "<example>You know &oacute; is an accented character</example>";
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance(); // instantiate XMLInputFactory
    inputFactory.setXMLResolver(new MyEntityResolver()); // Append custom entity resolver
    XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())); // create XMLStreamReader for the xml
    xmlStreamReader.next(); // reads <example>
    xmlStreamReader.next(); // reads the text inside <example> tag
    System.out.println("Text is: " + xmlStreamReader.getText());
    xmlStreamReader.next();
}

class MyEntityResolver implements XMLResolver {
    @Override
    public Object resolveEntity(String publicID, String systemID, String baseURI, String namespace) throws XMLStreamException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream("huehey!!".getBytes());
    }
}
```

}

Executing `testXMLResolver()` outputs first:

> Text is: You know

And then, when the last `next()` is executed it throws the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,27]
Message: The entity "oacute" was referenced, but not declared.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:601)
    at Test.testXMLResolver(Test.java:21)
    at Test.main(Test.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

**First:** I don't know why MyXMLResolver is not resolving the entity

**Second:** Why does the exception is thorwn in the last `next()` and not the previous one? because the text is parsed in the previous one.

**PS:** I make the `resolveEntity(...)` to return an `InputStream` because the documentation of the method says that:

> Retrieves a resource. This resource can be of the following three return types: (1) java.io.InputStream (2) javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader (3) java.xml.stream.XMLEventReader

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it because you have not declared ó ("uacute") ?
something like this maybe:

```
<!DOCTYPE definition [<!ENTITY oacute "&#243;">]>
```

Comment: You can do it that way, but then you would have to add all possible entities there, and there are a lot. I think it wouldn't be a good idea to maintain them manually. And doing it that way you wouldn't need the XMLResolver. I want the XMLResolver to use a third-party tool to resolve the entities.

Comment: where are you using the third party tool? I guess, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Hi @Sara, I'm not using it in this example, for simplicity's sake, and because it is not part of the problem. Here I just return "huehey!!" for any entity that arrives.