# failed to parse xml which contain html character entities in java

Tags: java, xml

When xml consist of html character entities, it throwing exception like this

```
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared general entity "ensp"
at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,66475]
```

Is there any way declared general entity so that I doesnot have to deal with this exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can edit the XML you're parsing, and the XML has a DOCTYPE declaration at the begin of the document, you need to add an entity declaration for `ensp`:

```
<!ENTITY ensp "&#8194;">
```

If you can edit the XML, but it hasn't a DOCTYPE declaration, you can make up a generic one such as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!ELEMENT root ANY>
  <!ENTITY ensp "&#8184;">
]>
... content ...
```

where `root` is replaced by the document element (the root element) of the XML data you have.

If you want to have all HTML entities expanded into numeric character entities (not just `ensp`), have a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#named-character-references or http://sgmljs.net/docs/html5.html#named-character-references.

If you don't have access to or can't change or don't want to change the XML (such as when you're pulling it from a network), then you might have luck by using Java's JAXP API to develop a custom `EntityResolver` and have your XML parsing pipeline using your custom entity resolver  (cf. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html).

Comment: @BibekShakya the general technique for StAX/woodstox is explained in eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971191/custom-entity-resolver-for-xmlstreamreader-not-working though I'm seeing that it didn't work out for the poster who seems to have the exact same problem as yours: that references to undeclared entities aren't valid in XML and get rejected. If you want to parse HTML, I suggest to use an HTML or SGML parser rather than an XML parser, though the options for Java are limited.

Answer (score 1):

The entity "ensp" is a space character entity, you could parse the XML/HTML for that attribute then replace with something different.

```
        File file = new File(yourFile);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(file);

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(inputLine);
        }

        String content = stringBuilder.toString();
        content = content.replace("ensp;", " ");
```

As an example.

Edit: Sorry mistook what you asked. This probably isn't the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your missing some config for Woodstox XML parser:

https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/configuring-woodstox-xml-parser-woodstox-specific-properties-1ce5030a5173

> P_TREAT_CHAR_REFS_AS_ENTS (default: false): Normally character references (like &) are simply expanded and reported as part of character data; but if this property is set to true they will instead be reported as ENTITY tokens. This may occasionally be useful when trying to fully reproduce input representation of an XML document, including choice of escaping of special characters.
>   NOTE: this only works for textual content — it is not possible to support for attribute values (as there are no separate tokens; attributes are accessible via START_ELEMENT token only)

Api docs:
http://fasterxml.github.io/woodstox/javadoc/5.0/com/ctc/wstx/api/WstxInputProperties.html#P_TREAT_CHAR_REFS_AS_ENTS